# Which J2EE Role need to be enabled to post in the Activity Stream of other user

Tags: ibm-sbt

Currently I am developing an XPages application with integration with IBM Connections.
We would like to post an entry to the Activity Stream of the manager of the user.
In the documentation of distributed events there is link to the Roles. But there are so many different.
So I was wondering which Role should be assigned to use the distributed events
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+API+Documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Distributing_events&content=pdcontent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can edit the turstedExternal Application Role

Navigate to https://${HOSTNAME}:9044/ibm/console/login.do?action=secure
Enter User ID : wasadmin
Enter Password : lcsecret
Click Login

Expand Applications > Application Types
Click on WebSphere Enterprise Applications

Find Widget Container

Click on "Security role to user/group mapping"

Add your trusted user to the trustedExternalApplication

A doc I wrote on this is at... 
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/dx/How_to_update_the_quickstart_to_support_Widgets

Comment: you can also use the microblog to direct the message to another user.