# Posting an entry from IBM Social Business Toolkit playground to on premises Connections

Tags: ibm-sbt

I am trying to post entry to community activity stream from IBM Social Business toolkit playground (Domino 9, SBT SDK version 20130602) to on premises Connections install. I am using the playground's existing JavaScript snippets but changed the communityID to match to community UUID in my Connections install. I don't have the OAuth2 configured.

I get an error "Error code:403, message:You are not authorized to perform the requested action."

I am able to get data from Connections. For example "Get Updates From A Community" -snippet works. But I am not able to post anything to Connections.

Do I need a working OAuth2 to be able to post entries or is there something else what prevents posting entries to Connections activity streams?

I tried to add a role to my account according to this post [Which J2EE Role need to be enabled to post in the Activity Stream of other user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589455/which-j2ee-role-need-to-be-enabled-to-post-in-the-activity-stream-of-other-user) but it did not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the post entry working. The issue seems to be the browser what I used.

Posting entry did not work with Chrome but with Firefox everything worked as expected. So there seems to be some problems with Chrome and posting entries from the playground. Getting data from Connections works also with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you prompted for basic authentication (either basic auth or OAuth would would work)? Or are you just accessing public communities?
Can you try to go to the authentication snippets, log in if not already (basic auth),and try the snippet again? If you still have a 403, it might be because your user doesn't have enough rights.

Comment: I am authenticated to playground in Domino. I have been using the Authentication Summary snippet to authenticate to Connections with basic authentication. If I don't do the basic authentication to Connections, then get type actions (Get Updates From a Community) give me the login prompt. However, I just noticed that the post entry gives me "You are not authorized" error directly whether I am authenticated to Connections or not. So getting that error with post entry snippet(s) does not seem to be affected with authentication.

Comment: in your domino notes.ini or in your configuration document for the server, do you have all methods enabled for the server? sometimes folks just have get enabled, and no put/post/delete.    also, what version of domino?

Comment: Domino 9 and Connections 4.0. I should have had all the methods enabled, but just to make sure I created a separate Internet Site document for the server and rebooted it. Does that setting really have an effect to playground post entry success?

Comment: well, post for oauth is an alternative, and it's good to check that's enabled.

Comment: out of curiosity, when you do the post, and dance, what does your systemout.log look like?